# preparedStatement Insert query get error NullPointerException for primary key in java with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, crud

When i am coding in `netbeans`, `java` and `mysql`, in some point i couldn't insert values where db table having auto increment primary key (`user_id`).

```
         String sql = "INSERT INTO `user`(`fname`, `lname`, `uemail`, 
        `upass`, `role_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        //ps.setInt(1,2);
        ps.setString(1, fname);
        ps.setString(2, lname);
        ps.setString(3, uemail);
        ps.setString(4, upass);
        ps.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(urole));
```

I get below error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
>               java.lang.NullPointerException
>             at mxm.MainFrame.btnURegisterActionPerformed(MainFrame.java:1365)

Comment: What's happening at line 1365 ?

Comment: maybe `ps` is null or `urole` is null - also leave a space before `(` and also I don't think the ugly backticks are needed

Comment: String fname = txtUFName.getText();
        String lname = txtULName.getText();
        String uemail = txtUEmail.getText();
        String upass = String.valueOf(pwdUSet.getPassword());
        String setpass = String.valueOf(pwdUConfirm.getPassword());
        String urole = cmbURole.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Connection con;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Statement st;

Comment: *PreparedStatement ps = null;*

Comment: try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ji_computer?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "");

            String sql = "INSERT INTO `user`(`fname`, `lname`, `uemail`, `upass`, `role_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            //ps.setInt(1,2);
            ps.setString(1, fname);
            ps.setString(2, lname);
            ps.setString(3, uemail);
            ps.setString(4, upass);
            ps.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(urole));

Comment: You never initialise `ps`.

Comment: PreparedStatement ps = null; – Scary Wombat it is auto initialized. down in the code i use ps = con.prepareStatement(sql,PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            boolean execute = ps.execute();
            ps.close();

Comment: You should edit your **question**, don't use comments for additional information (especially not for code, as it becomes unreadable in comments).